# count number of characters before a number

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MySQL 5.6 database, I want to trim all the contents that fall after the space before the first number in a string, and then insert the results into a new table.  For example, `SELECT id, strcolumn FROM sometable` gives values:

```
8976    complicated 200 some other info
8977    something else 400 even more info
8978    intricate 300 lots of extra characters
```

I want the new table to reduce the above to look like:

```
8976    complicated
8977    something else
8978    intricate
```

How do I alter the following statement so that it creates the new, edited table?

```
CREATE TABLE newtablename AS SELECT id, strcolumn FROM sometable
```

In Java, I would iterate through the string one character at a time looking for a numeric value, then subtract 1 from the index of the first numeric value, and trim the string to end at the specified index, resulting in a 100% success rate. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: so you just want to take a string with mixed alpha numeric and trim it up to the last character before a number (sounds like a job for a regular expression though I haven't used these in mysql myself) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: @shaunhusain Yes, that is what I want.  However, when I use regular expressions, I notice that they have 98+% match rates.  My data set has 200000 rows, so a 99.5% match rate would produce 1000 errors, which is not acceptable. I want a 100% success rate.

Comment: Sorry not enough of an SQL expert to tell you if there is or isn't, perhaps since your more comfortable in Java you could just script it up that way, 200,000 rows isn't really that large so it shouldn't take much time to process it in Java.

Comment: How about exporting the data (`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`), process it with a proper programming language and reimport (`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`). You could also include the data handling from/to db in the programm, if the task is likely to be repeated on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBSTRING_INDEX this is the ugliest SQL that I have ever written: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a79b4/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (id int primary key, strcolumn text);

INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (8976, 'complicated 200 some other info'), 
(8977, 'something else 400 even more info'), 
(8978, 'intricate 300 lots of extra characters ');

CREATE TABLE newtablename AS 
  SELECT id, 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           strcolumn, 
           ' 1', 1), ' 2', 1), ' 3', 1), ' 4', 1), ' 5', 1), ' 6', 1), ' 7', 1), ' 8', 1), ' 9', 1), ' 0', 1) as strcolumn 
FROM sometable;
```

This is ugly and inefficient. MySQL can search using Regular Expressions, but it cannot return substrings based on them. I **really recommend** using an UDF or a client-side script, this may be the RE you may use: /^([^0-9]*)\s[0-9]*/ Or at least, create a function to encapsulate this.

The question may not be 100% clear, as you should specify what result do you want if the number is not preceded by a space, or if it is the first character.